# How to solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = a(t)*x^2+b(t)*x+c(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Be the equation $$\frac{dx}{dt} = a(t)*x^2+b(t)*x+c(t)$$ where $$a,b,c : I =[α,β] ⊂ R → R $$ are continuous function.

a) How can I found the solutions to the equation knowing a particular one $ρ_0$ ?

b) If $a(t)= 1, b(t)= -2e^{2t}, c(t)=e^{4t}+2e^{2t}$ and the equation admits the particular solution $ρ_0(t)= αe^2t$ what is the general solution to the equation?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: (b) It would be clearer if you put $x_0(t)=e^{2t}$ as the particular solution. To get the general solution put $x=x_0+y$ and you find the equation for $y$ is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

b)

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 1*x^2 - 2e^{2t}*x + e^{4t} + 2e^{2t}$

$ => \frac{dx}{dt} - 2e^{2t} = (x - e^{2t})^2  $   .......... eq 1

Put $x - e^{2t} = u $  .............eq 2

Differentiate both sides w.r.t. t to get:

$\frac{dx}{dt} - 2e^{2t} = \frac{du}{dt}   $.................eq 3

Put eq 3 and eq 2 in eq 1 to get:

$ \frac{du}{dt} = u^2$

or $ \frac{du}{u^2} = dt$

or $ \int u^{-2}du = \int dt$

or $ -u^{-1} = t + αe^2t$

or $ \frac{-1}{x-e^{2t}} = t + αe^2t$

or $ \frac{-1}{(t)(1 + αe^2)} = x-e^{2t}$